# PHP Pagination issue mysql and php showing same data on all pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am having issues with some pagination with data i get from a MySQL database in PHP.

My code is below. Basically what happens is it creates the right amount of pages however each page shows the same data and doesn't even show only 5 rows per page.

I'm really stuck. This is my first time trying pagination. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];

        if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
        { 
            $pagenum = 1; 
        }   else
            {
                $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
            }

        //Count the number of results.
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` = '' AND `requestedby` != '$id'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($data);

        //Set the number of results to be displayed per page.
        $page_rows = 5;

        //This tells us the page number of our last page 
        $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

         //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 
        if ($pagenum < 1) 
        { 
            $pagenum = 1; 
        }   elseif ($pagenum > $last) 
            { 
                $pagenum = $last; 
            }

        //This sets the range to display in our query 
        $max = 'LIMIT ' . ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

        //This is the query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it.
        $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` = '' AND `requestedby` != '$id' '$max'") or die(mysql_error());

        //Work out writers earnings based on prices.
        //100 Words - $1.25
        //300 Words - $2.50
        //500 Words - $4.00
        //700 Words - $5.50
        //1000 Words - $8.00
        $_100earnings = "0.65";
        $_300earnings = "1.25";
        $_500earnings = "2.50";
        $_700earnings = "3.00";
        $_1000earnings = "5.00";
    ?>
    <!-- main -->
    <div id="main">
    <center><h2>Write Articles</h2></center>
    <br />Available Projects:
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td>Length:</td>
            <td>Writers Earnings:</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            //This is where you display your query results
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data_p))
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $info['keywords'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $info['length'] . "</td>";
                switch ($info['length'])
                {
                    case 100:
                        $writersearnings = $_100earnings;
                        break;
                    case 300:
                        $writersearnings = $_300earnings;
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        $writersearnings = $_500earnings;
                        break;
                    case 700:
                        $writersearnings = $_700earnings;
                        break;
                    case 1000:
                        $writersearnings = $_1000earnings;
                        break;
                }
                echo "<td>$" . $writersearnings . "</td>";
                //echo $info['Name']; 
                echo "</tr>";
            }

        ?>
    </table>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
        // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
        echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


        // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.  
        if ($pagenum == 1) 
        {
        }   else 
            {
                 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";
                 echo " ";
                 $previous = $pagenum - 1;
                 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";   
            } 

        //just a spacer
        echo " ---- ";

        //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links
        if ($pagenum == $last) 
        {

        }   else 
            {
                 $next = $pagenum + 1;

                 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

                 echo " ";

                 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";
            }
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 4):

use this code, remove `'` around `$max` in query, when you add `'` around `$max` the query becomes `select.... from.... where..... 'LIMIT.....'` and it fails the query.

```
$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `content` = '' AND `requestedby` != '$id' $max") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. Any reason why the ' creates problems?

Comment: @KriiV Accepting answer is good habit , when it solves your problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify `LIMIT` in your query `LIMIT offset,count`

`$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM`articles`WHERE`content`= '' AND`requestedby`!= '$id' '$max'") or die(mysql_error());`

Remove the `'` quotes from `'$max'`

```
$data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE content= '' AND requestedby!= '".$id."' ".$max) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. Why did that create an issue?

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun deprecation process. See the red box? Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Because mysql will treat anything inside `'` as a string but actually it is a keyword, So there should not be any quotes around it

Comment: @PrasanthBendra It's better to actually use the comment which contains the links, then the statements within it make a little more sense..